# How to graph the data from an array using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I need to draw a graph so that on the x axis there will be "i" data, and on the y axis there will be "massAngle [i]" data. I tried to do it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < massAngle.length; i++) {
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("1");
    series.add(i, massAngle[i]);

    XYSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Долгота и Широта",
            "Долгота", "Широта", seriesCollection, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150, 470));
    panel.add(chartPanel);
}
```

Comment: but ? what's the problem ?

Comment: I don't know JFreeChart very well, but in your code you are creating a new chart for every angle. I don't think that's what you want. I'd try to put everything outside the loop except for _series.add(...)_

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `XYSeriesCollection`, a new `JFChart` a new `ChartPanel` for **each** element of your array, you have to do it once : create a `XYSeries` add all your data and build *one* chart :

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("1");
for (int i = 0; i < massAngle.length; i++) {
    series.add(i, massAngle[i]);
}

XYSeriesCollection seriesCollection = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Долгота и Широта", "Долгота", 
                 "Широта", seriesCollection, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);

final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1150, 470));
panel.add(chartPanel);
```

Comment: @VIRICH ;) don't hesite to accept/vote up the answer, it'll guide the new people which look for accepted post at first ;)